# Order by boolean column produce duplicate rows when paging in sql server

Tags: sql-server, paging

I work on this table :

[image: Order by boolean column produce duplicate rows when paging in sql server]

When do paging using the `IsAdmin` column, the result will contain duplicated rows. This is my query :

```
SELECT [UserId],[IsAdmin],[Date] FROM [Groups].[GroupMembers]
WHERE ([GroupId] = 5)
ORDER BY [IsAdmin] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS ONLY
```

And the second query :

```
SELECT [UserId],[IsAdmin],[Date] FROM [Groups].[GroupMembers]
WHERE ([GroupId] =5)    
ORDER BY [IsAdmin] DESC
OFFSET 6 ROWS FETCH NEXT 6 ROWS ONLY
```

The result for the two queries is :

[image: Order by boolean column produce duplicate rows when paging in sql server]

But if user the `Date` column, I get result without duplicate.

My question is that why using boolean produce duplicate rows ?

Comment: It doesn't produce duplicate rows. It is a useless column for an order by. You need to add another column to your order by or you have no idea what order they will be returned. It will do whatever it wants for order inside of each value of your boolean. Maybe simply adding UserId as a second column would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your order by is non-deterministic. As there are a lot of rows where Is Admin = 0, you aren't guaranteed that the same rows will be selected each time.

If you change your query to be

```
SELECT [UserId],[IsAdmin],[Date] FROM [Groups].[GroupMembers]
WHERE ([GroupId] = 5)
ORDER BY [IsAdmin] DESC, [UserId]
```

then you won't get the same row appearing twice (assuming that [UserId] is unique).

Actually, this still won't guarantee that a row won't appear twice. If rows are inserted between calls, and the new rows would have appeared on the current page, then some of the rows actually shown on the current page will be re-shown on the next page as they have been bumped down the order.